# Why do we use dynamic memory in ccNUMA systems when we talk about data distribution into locality domains by first touch policy?

Tags: linux, parallelism, multiprocessor, numa

In many books, when they talk about first touch policy in ccNUMA systems they are using dynamic memory allocation when they distribute data across locality domains. What if, for example, we have an array in stack?Does first touch policy work in the same way?